# What can I do about a privacy url?

Tags: android

I am trying to put my android app on the market and the last thing I need is a privacy url. The problem is I don't have a website. I just created this app as my first project ever. Is there something I can do to get around this? Can I use a blog site or a facebook page or twitter page? I would really not have to pay for a website and I don't have the time to create my own website right now. I was just hoping to put my app up finally after all this work and I'm stuck. I looked online but cant really seem to find anything without having a website already. I can write my own but it still leaves me with the fact that I don't have a website to post it onto.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that really mandatory now? I created an app 1 month ago and I didn't have any privacy policy. I just checked the box "Not submitting a privacy policy URL at this time".

Comment: Yeah I noticed that about 20 minutes after my post but decided it would still be a good idea to know what I could do in order to get a privacy policy up. Thanks though!

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can create a [free site on Google Sites](http://sites.google.com) and create a [boilerplate privacy policy](http://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/free-privacy-policy-generator.php) if you need that too.

Comment: I am using Google Analytics in my Android App. Do I still need to have a privacy URL, now that they have made it optional. As in, am I legally required to provide a privacy policy if I am using Google Analytics in my app.

Comment: the site asked me for my name and email address for the last question and wouldn't give me my privacy policy otherwise. you can use https://10minutemail.com/ to create a temporary email to hold on to your privacy ;)

Comment: When I do this, I get "You are not allowed that domain for a privacy policy URL." even though I verified I'm using the same account for managing the Play Store listing and the google site

Comment: second link charges to generate the privacy policy.

Answer (score 39):

## website hosting

[checkout GitHub's GitHub Pages services](https://pages.github.com/). they host a simple static website for you for free! basic instructions:

1. create a public repository on [GitHub](http://github.com) named `[username].github.io` (replace "[username]")
2. commit an `index.html` file to the root of the repo.
3. you can see your site online at `http://[username].github.io/`.

## privacy policy

[basic privacy policy template here](https://www.docracy.com/mobileprivacy)....it'll give you a template that you can simply copy and paste and modify to fit your needs. unlike most other places that are after your money and/or personal information!!!

even some of the free ones have you fill out your survey, and ask you for email at the last moment...annoying!

Answer (score 20):

- Try [App Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/#)
- Download as an HTML/Copy the Content
- Host it on [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/)/[Google Sites](https://sites.google.com/)

Comment: Google Sites, I really did not know it existed, thanks for such a wonderful idea.

Answer (score 8):

I just created a Google Doc, set its sharing to public, and put the shareable link in the privacy url.  Easy.  :-)

EDIT:  I noticed I needed to create a new document for each app, otherwise I got the error:

> You are not allowed that domain for a privacy policy URL.

Comment: Hi, can you please share the contents of the policy? My apps use nothing of user data like email, location, Ads, etc.

Comment: @Maulik Mine uses ads.  This is it:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EybP0y6I2VUX3AXg-_HtL54Q6sQZWhLzOXLLB4AieTA

Answer (score 2):

You could start a Google Groups newsgroup for your app.  Post a sticky with your privacy policy and lock the thread.  Provide the link to that sticky as your privacy link.  Update it as needed if your policies have to change.

Easy peasy.