# Do I need a own website to publish my Android app?

Tags: android, android-studio, publishing

When publishing an Android App on the Google Play Developer Console, you should specify a URL to the privacy statement (leftmost on "All Apps" -> "Store Entry" -> relatively far down "Privacy Statement"), but if you don't have your own website, do you really have to create one? 
My app doesn't record any data, the user doesn't have to log in at all or similar.
Has anyone have any experiences, maybe anyone of you have even published their own app?
Thanks in advance
L.

Comment: You have your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597666/what-can-i-do-about-a-privacy-url/13598193

Comment: How are you planning on marketing your app without a Web site?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do about a privacy url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597666/what-can-i-do-about-a-privacy-url)

Comment: You used to be able to select an option that said I'm not supplying a privacy policy link at this time, and Google would link to their own generic policy disclaimer.  But in recent years they have made it required.  The first comment above was really good to know!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No**, not a must. You can follow an alternative method to publish your privacy policy as mentioned below.

Use [Firebase Privacy Policy Generator](https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/) to create a privacy policy for your app.

Then you can download the generated privacy policy or copy contents in it and paste them in a Google doc. ***Publish*** the Google Doc.(You can find the option in File menu). When it is published, you will get a **link/url** for the Document so that any one who has the **link/url** can access the document.

Now, you can provide the above **link/url** in the Play Console when the privacy policy statement is required.